# Script in D3.js make Chrome crash

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, crash, d3.js

I have written this code in javascript using D3 to make an animation for a website, somthing like an "atom-looklike" core. The final effect it's exacly like i would but every time i try to open it with chrome it crashes.

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the "translateAlong" function. Any ideas?

here is the script  [Core](http://www.danielpasqualini.altervista.com/prove/nucleo.html) , it usually crashes after a while, just have to wait.

Have you got any ideas?
thank you!

Edit: Firefox doesn't crashes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var divWidth = window.innerWidth - 25;
var divHeight = window.innerHeight - 25;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.style("background-color", "#000000")
       .attr("width", divWidth)
       .attr("height", divHeight);


var sampleData=new Array();

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .interpolate("basis-closed");

sampleData = [];    

var r = 40;
var count = 0;
var n = 8;  
var paths= new Array();

for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    paths[i] = svg.append("path")
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("fill", "none");
}   
var xapp,yapp;



setInterval(function()
{       
    for(var j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        sampleData = [];
        for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            xapp = (divWidth/2 + Math.cos((i*(2*Math.PI/10)))*r)+Math.random()*r*2-r;
            yapp = (divHeight/2 + Math.sin((i*(2*Math.PI/10)))*r)+Math.random()*r*2-r;
            sampleData[i] = [xapp,yapp];
        }
        paths[j]
      .data([sampleData])
      .transition()
      .duration(300)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis-closed"));
    }
}, 200);

setInterval(function()
{   
    for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        svg.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 2)
          .style("fill","white")
          .style("stroke","white")              
          .transition()
          .duration(2000)
          .ease("linear")
          .attrTween("transform",translateAlong(paths[i].node()))
          .each("end", function() { 
                          d3.select(this).remove(); })
    }
}, 300);

function translateAlong(path) {
    var l = path.getTotalLength();
    return function(d, i, a) {
        return function(t) {
            var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
            return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
        };
    };
}  
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you're appending circles ad infinitum. This will sooner or later make the browser crash as you're running out of memory.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff This removes the circle at the end of the transition: .each("end", function() { 
      d3.select(this).remove(); })

Comment: Ah yes, of course. This might be what's causing the problem though -- have you tried simply putting `.remove()` instead?

Comment: Same problem, nothing changes

Comment: `d3.select(this).remove()` calls `parent.removeChild(this);` in d3.js library. If garbage collection is working ok, then this should not be problem. The next suspect could be `var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);` from function `translateAlong()`. Here you 'create' a bunch of SVGPoints which are a kind of matrix. I don't know if they accumulate or are somehow cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

#### *You are creating new elements faster than you are destroying old ones!*

Check your code. Your interval triggers `circle` element creation every 300 milliseconds whereas the circles get removed only on completing a 2000 milliseconds long transition.
So, by the time an existing circle is removed, at least 6 new circles are created.

[**Here's a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/9pZ2r/) proving this observation.

Just changed the `milliseconds` of your second `setInterval` (that creates circles) and see for yourself. *Ensure that you keep this value greater than or equal to the `transition().duration` value.*

Also, a friendly tip: Consider using d3 `enter`, `update`, `exit` technique. That will help you avoid out-of-fashion `for` loops to a large extent.